# Error after running docker-compose without adding puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, bundle-install

I forgot to add puma in Gemfile before run docker-compose. after the docker-compose download and build all dependencies. It come up with an error that I bring in the block here.

```
app_1        | bundler: command not found: puma
app_1        | Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
ibuy7_db_backup_1 exited with code 0
ibuy7_app_1 exited with code 127
```

How should I solve this problem. Plz help me

Comment: Post your docker-compose file

Answer (score 1):

If your Dockerfile doesn't have commands to install bundler and other required files then then the image will not have them when you start the container.

If you run docker-compose run app gem install bundler then the new files are lost when that container stops.

You may want to add 'gem install bundler; bundle install; bundle exec rails s' to your docker-compose.yml CMD

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. I used this command "docker-compose run app bundle install"
to install puma and it seams that it installed but steel I have same error.

`Attaching to ibuy7_db_1, ibuy7_db_backup_1, ibuy7_app_1, ibuy7_nginx_1
app_1        | bundler: command not found: puma
app_1        | Install missing gem executables with bundle install
ibuy7_db_backup_1 exited with code 0
db_1         | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-08-13 07:30:28 UTC
db_1         | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1         | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1         | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1         | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1         | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1         | LOG:  shutting down
db_1         | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1         | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-08-13 07:35:16 UTC
db_1         | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1         | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1         | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1         | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1         | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1         | LOG:  shutting down
db_1         | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1         | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-08-13 07:41:30 UTC
db_1         | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1         | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1         | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
ibuy7_app_1 exited with code 127
nginx_1      | 2017/08/13 07:44:27 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
nginx_1      | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
ibuy7_nginx_1 exited with code 1`